# FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions. Is this the right way to fix this?

Tags: firebase

Alright so I was creating an application that works with firebase and when a user signs in, user's ID is stored in the data base. But when I was creating this I ran into an error that would pop up after a user signs in `FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.`.

I did some research. It was the firestore rules, which were set to default as

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

I changed this as

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

That's right from false to true. Is the right way to do it? Help would be appreciated.

Comment: This article, [How to fix Firestore Error: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-fix-firestore-error-permission-denied-missing-or-insufficient-permissions-777d591f404) will help you for sure understand everything you need to know about this error.

Comment: @AlexMamo the link is locked :( I guess to open it I'll need to upgrade my account on Medium.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just testing and no one is going to use it it's fine but please, keep in mind that this kind of ruleset allows everyone to read and write to each of your files under the documents collection.

I ran into this kind of problem too while starting out with firebase and I know it's overwhelming but I would suggest you try and implement a ruleset more secure following this [get started guide by google](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started).

Let me know if you need any further information.

Comment: What kind of instruction do I need to add/change so as make this suitable for both development and production?

Comment: This will vary widely based on what you are trying to implement. Usually, you would have different conditions whether someone is logged in and if they are trying to access their own account or someone else's, or if they are trying to read public content that cannot be changed or making a post that anybody can read. Firebase offers a nice tool to try your ruleset based on different conditions so I would suggest you try experimenting and tuning it while you develop it.